# Azure SSRS Report Server not accessible outside of VM machine

Tags: azure, server, report, virtual

I can connect to the report server URL from the VM but not from the outside.  I have configured port 80 etc.  I have reviewed pretty much all of the configuration suggestions I could find but still no luck.  Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is forum about questions/answers of problems related to programming. It is not a support forum network problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are basically 3 moving pieces here.
1. Firewall on the VM.
2. Network Security Group on the Azure Side.
3. Actual application listening on port 80.

Judging by your post I'd assume you didn't open up port 80 on the Network Security Group. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-nsg-quickstart-portal) link for details.